# How to iterate a set of functions without nested for loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, iteration

I'm very new to creating functions and alternatives to loops, but I'm trying to run a set of dplyr functions on a dataframe. However, the dataframe needs to be split by Transmitter and Station. I'm currently using a nested for loop, but as I expected, this is taking an extremely long time, and is not efficient. Here is the structure of my data.

```
> str(example)
> str(Det17)
'data.frame':   43423 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ DateTime   : POSIXct, format: "2017-07-31 02:57:42" "2017-07-31 13:10:27" "2017-08-09 09:52:12" "2017-07-31 02:59:30" ...
 $ Transmitter: Factor w/ 58 levels "1657","1658",..: 38 38 46 38 38 38 38 29 38 38 ...
 $ Station    : Factor w/ 41 levels "A0","A1","A2",..: 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 ...
>
```

Here is the code I'm attempting:

```
for( i in Det17$Station){
  for( j in Det17$Transmitter){



Example <- Det17%>%
  filter(Station == i & Transmitter == j)%>%
  arrange(DateTime)%>%
  mutate(difftime = difftime(lead(DateTime),DateTime, tz = 'EST', units = 'secs'))%>%
  filter(difftime < 30)
      if(length(Example$difftime) > 0) {
        print("TRUE")
        } else {
      next
    }

  }
}
```

Basically, I want to filter my data by every combination of Station and transmitter levels. I want to arrange the dataframe by datetime, add a new column that is the difference between two consecutive times, filter again by difftimes less than 30 seconds, then print "TRUE" if the length of the new variable is greater than 0. Ideally I would know which combinations led to an output of "TRUE" but I haven't gotten there yet.

EDIT:

Here is the group of functions as a function not a loop:

```
function(x){
  arrange(DateTime)%>%
  mutate(difftime = difftime(lead(DateTime),DateTime, tz = 'EST', units = 'secs'))%>%
  filter(difftime < 30)
      if(length(Example$difftime) > 0) {
        print("TRUE")
        } else {
      next
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The split function is helpful here. You can split your data frame by the dimensions you want to iterate over.

`DetSplit <- split(Det17, list(Det17$Station, Det17$Transmitter))`

Then you can use an lapply function to act on the list of resulting data frames one by one.

`DetProcessed <- lapply(DetSplit, my_function_name)`

then bind it all together

`DetProcessed <- data.table::rbindlist(DetProcess)`

You can also do this with pipes instead of breaking it out into separate objects.

Comment: That makes sense. Since I don't have much experience using lists either, how do I change the new function to work with the newly created list?